# Centroid data points for US states

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, centroids

I need to map some data related to states in the USA. I have polygon data for each state but my dataset needs to be mapped by points.

How do I find centroid points for each state (not polygons)?

Answer (score 3):

The ESRI website has a lot of great documentation for almost anything you need. This article will give you a step-by-step guide on how to get the centroid point for each state:

**[Find the centroid of polygons using Calculate Geometry in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-find-the-centroid-of-polygons-using-calculate-ge-000021849)**